# How do I remove the gaps between charts in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this dashboard I'm building in SSRS and when I view in the actual report view, there's a huge gap between the 'sales by period' chart and the '% sales by type' chart. You can see in design view that there isn't any space between these charts so I'm not sure why the report view has such a huge space. I've tried messing with the margins of the charts to no avail.

[image: design view]

[image: report view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS objects are vertically aligned on the object boundaries.

In your example, in design view, the bottom boundary of the table for "2016" is higher then the top boundary for % Sales by Type table. Since "2016" grew to a much taller size, the top of % Sales by Type is pushed down accordingly.

To work around this, you need to put objects in rectangles so the renderer doesn't consider the individual object boundaries in relation to each other.

If you put Sales by Period and % Sales by Type in a rectangle together, the boundary of objects outside that rectangle should not affect the spacing of the objects inside the rectangle.

On a related note, SSRS respects the white space you've left between objects.  For example, the Diff table and Units By Category have around .6" verticle white space.  If you have a result that has no value for the 2016 table, or if Diff grows enough to exceed the height of the 2016 table, SSRS will still include that additional white between Diff and the chart.

In addition, you should not use white space for the margins around your objects.  The body of the report fits within the margins of the page.  Adding that additional white space on the left and right will affect printing.  It is best practice to align objects to the left side of the body, shrink the body width to the right most component boundary and then set your margins in the page properties.